# Virtual Box VT-x

Tags: virtualbox, vt-x

I have an Intel I5 processor and an Asus B85M-E motherboard. The only setting in the BIOS concerning VT-x says "Enabled". I am running the 64 bit version of Windows 7. But Virtual Box says that VT-x is not supported on this hardware. Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: Exactly which "I5" are you using?

Comment: Check around in different sections of the BIOS. On one computer I've, one of the settings was in the CPU features section and another one in the security section or some such.

Comment: It's obvious that he is talking about a Core i5.

Comment: @AndrewJ.Brehm Not all I5's are the same.  Different models a have different features. I'm suspecting the one he has may not have hardware virtualization support.

Comment: At a first glance I cannot see an i5 without VT-x: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_i5

Comment: @user312321 Did you configure a setting called "Secure Virtual Machine Mode" in the BIOS?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same morherboard and core i5 4400 proc and I had the same issue. I solved it by disabling Hyper-V. Its not possible to run Hyper-V alongside Virtualbox.